# how to pass form data to a php file using Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I created this model (in Controller I save data in it):

```
config: {
     fields: [
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'email', type: 'string'},
     ],
     proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '/php/user.php',
     }
}
```

And the php (user.php) file I made this, but this way isn't working:

```
<?php
    include "conect.php";

    $n = $_POST['name'];
    $e = $_POST['email'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (name, email) VALUES ('$n', '$e')");
?>
```

so how can I pass data to php and insert to my database?

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = Ext.create('User', { name: 'my name', email: 'test@test.com' });

user.save();
```

Comment: I did this in my Controller but I'm receiving this error:           POST http://localhost/php/user.php?_dc=1343735631656 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You should have web server installed and running on the localhost with application named 'php' in it.